# The Koebe $\frac{1}{4}$-Theorem

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, power-series

[image]

I am trying to understand the above theorem. I have problem understanding the last two lines of the proof. Why is the Koebe function the only function that omits $|w|<\frac{1}{4}$?

Source: [http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~bianchi/teaching/2018_M3P60/2016-F-GCA-chp6.pdf](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/%7Ebianchi/teaching/2018_M3P60/2016-F-GCA-chp6.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theorem 6.4 (Bieberbach's theorem) in those notes states that $| a_2  | \le 2$ for $f \in S$, with equality if and only if $f$ is a rotation of the Koebe function.

If $f \in S$ omits a value $w$ with $|w| = 1/4$ then
$$
 4 = \left| \frac 1w \right| = \left| a_2 + \frac 1w  - a_2 \right|
\le \left| a_2 + \frac 1w \right |  + |a_2| \le 2 + 2 = 4 \, .
$$
Then equality must hold everywhere in that inequality chain, in particular $| a_2  | = 2$, and then Theorem 6.4 shows that $f$ is a rotation of the Koebe function.